# Ceramic caps and applied voltage

Tags: capacitor, ceramic

I'm using a 22u 6.3V X5R 0805 ceramic capacitor to filter out a 3.3V supply (for a buck converter.) I've heard that applied voltage has an effect on the capacitance of certain ceramic caps; a higher voltage causes a reduction in capacitance. How true is this? Would it decrease too much as to not work as a suitable filter cap? I think 10-15u is probably the minimum for it to remain stable, although the ripple will probably increase at lower capacitance. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This page](http://my.execpc.com/~endlr/ceramic.html) has the following table:
[image]

So, if the 22uF is a 20% tolerance part such that is may actually be 17.6uF (-20%), and it is really 15uF (-15%) due to heating, it may be reduced to ~10.5uF (-30%) near its tolerance or **~14uF** (-5%) near its operating point. To reduce the effect, use a higher breakdown value capacitor.

Although [this webpage](http://www.cliftonlaboratories.com/capacitor_voltage_change.htm) tests much higher breakdown voltage ceramics, the results are illustrative:
[image]

[This part](http://www.avx.com/docs/Catalogs/cx5r.pdf), the [08056D226MAT2A](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=478-3647-2-ND) by AVX, states that it meets its tolerance tested at 0.5 V<sub>RMS</sub>, not close to its breakdown:

> For Cap > 10 μF, 0.5Vrms @ 120Hz

It also mentions that capacitance may change up to 12.5% over its load life, 7.5% due to soldering thermal shock, and 12% due to *flexure fissures* (cracks).

<sub>***Info tidbit:*** The term **X5R** means it is composed of a **class 2 dielectric** (ie: ceramic) that will maintain its capacitance to within 15% (18.7uF - 25.3uF) over a temperature range -55<sup>o</sup>C to 85<sup>o</sup>C.</sub>
Something that may interest you, though it has more to do with the final application than the question -- [the great 'pedia also mentions:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X7R)

> Due to its piezoelectric properties, they are subject to microphonics.

... And the previously [linked page](http://my.execpc.com/~endlr/ceramic.html):

> High-K ceramic capacitors can show significant piezoelectric effects; if you tap them they will produce a voltage spike.  This is caused by the barium titanate, the main material in high K ceramics.  The higher the K, the stronger this affect.

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of capacitance loss. The exact part is GRM21BR60J226ME39L - http://uk.farnell.com/murata/grm21br60j226me39l/capacitor-0805-22uf-6-3v/dp/1735531/.

Comment: I have footprint space for a 22u 10V 1206 cap - would it be advisable to place this instead of a 22u 6.3V 0805? I'm not currently placing it because of slightly higher cost of the 1206 cap vs. 0805 cap.

Comment: @ThomasO, [Here's an 0805 10V (21c/3000; $1.05/1).](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=587-1958-2-ND) Not sure about pros & cons of 0805 vs 1206, but 10V is definitely better than 6.3V. Are you going to be able to test the microphonics? Sounds interesting...

Comment: @tyblu, It's nice, but quite expensive (twice the price) and it seems I need to order min. 3000. Also, it would be bad to depend on a single capacitor manufacturer. There are several suppliers for 22u/6.3V caps.

Comment: @ThomasO, Are you designing for the military or Apple? Replacing this part would be trivial if the original manufacturer went kaput.

Comment: @tyblu, It's for a product which may sell thousands or just 10. But it's not military rated in any way, only -40 to +70 degrees C, maximum.

Comment: Would there be any way to design a capacitor so that it had maximum capacitance at some non-zero voltage value?  In scenarios involving intermittently-powered equipment, a cap which had much higher capacitance near 3.3 volts than at lower voltages could improve energy efficiency.  The physical analog of a constant cap would be a cylindrical water tank; a cap which decreases with voltage would be a flask that tapers inward at the top.  The type of cap I'd like to see would be (for purposes of the analogy) shaped like a water tower--narrow except near a certain operating range.

Comment: Interesting idea, @supercat! Worth a question or two, I'd say.